# Is this JK Rowling "pocketeded" story true?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

There's a Stephen Fry vs. JK Rowling story that periodically memes up:

> Just after the first Harry Potter book had been released, [Fry] was offered the role of narrating it for audiobooks. He hadn’t read it, and was simply told it was a children’s book, so figured it would be an easy afternoon's work. When he met JK Rowling, she mentioned that she was writing a sequel. Stephen replied very condescendingly “good for you”.
>
> A few years down the line, the books are selling well, and he is doing the recording for the Prisoner of Azkaban, when he runs into the phrase “Harry pocketed it”. Stephen could not say this line. It always came out as “Harry pocketeded it”, unless he said it ridiculously slowly. They tried time and time again to get it right, but to no avail. Eventually, he called up JK and asked if he could say “Harry put it in his pocket” instead. She thought for a moment, then said “no”, and hung up.
>
> The phrase “Harry pocketed it” appeared in the next four books.

There's a [video](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1561821463981052) (Facebook) where Fry confirms the main part of this. Is the final sentence true?

Comment: The phrase "*harry pocketed it*" only appears in one book, Goblet of Fire where it appears twice. The words "*pocketed it*" appear in books 1, 2, 4, 5 and 6 but not in books 2 & 7.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phiMuhhIjAM

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/3ttlp1/americans_miffed_at_lack_of_stephen_fry_harry/cx9fp0t

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no video of it. The story seems to have come from a [couple](https://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/3ttlp1/americans_miffed_at_lack_of_stephen_fry_harry/cx9fp0t) of [audience members](https://www.reddit.com/r/pettyrevenge/comments/3whguj/jk_rowlings_revenge/) at a stage show he did in December where he recounted the tale. As with most of these showbiz luvvie stories, I expect it needs to be taken with a huge shaker of salt.

Comment: @Richard Worth noting that the first of those two Reddit comments (by waywardwoodwork) is from 22 November and has the show as being “a couple of nights ago”, while the second (by Wolfpony) is from 12 December and has it as being “last week”. Unless Wolfpony is _seriously_ bad at remembering time, they can’t have gone to the same shows. Wolfpony is clearly (from her comments) from New Zealand, which fits with the Fry show in Auckland on 2 Dec; can’t tell from his comments where waywardwoodwork is from, but the show would have to be Perth on 17 Dec or Sydney on 21 Dec.

Comment: Also perhaps worth noting that if there is indeed a video of Fry confirming the main part of the story, then he’s changed his story. In [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptFf2NHeoec), which is at least two years old, he describes going to lunch with Rowling in the very early stages of their acquaintance and says that he suggested to her the book was so good there could be a series in it, to which she replied that she already had seven books planned out. That doesn’t really tally with his condescending remark here: either he knew it was a series, or he didn’t.

Comment: @RedCaio that's a nice video, but it puts an answer into the question.  You should edit it into an answer instead.

Comment: @TonyMeyer oops, I thought it was the video that you mentioned when you said "there's a video where Fry confirms the main part of this" so I thought I was simply adding to the question. : /

Comment: @RedCaio I thought I remembered that there was a video of the show (the NZ one probably, since I would have noticed that, being from NZ also).  I may be remembering that incorrectly.  The show would have only had the anecdote, whereas that video has the actual instances of the phrase (which is great for an answer).

Comment: @Tony I tried finding a recording of the Auckland (or Sydney, or Perth) show, but came up with nothing. There’s a recording of a Sydney show from 2010, but that doesn’t seem likely to be relevant. Possibly it was uploaded by someone onto YouTube and has since been removed for copyright reasons.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TonyMeyer you've formatted the story as a quote. Is there a source for that quote? Or is it just formatting?

Comment: @SQB - It's a commonly shared meme.

Comment: @valorum - Have you seen DavidS's answer?

Comment: @ibid - Yes, it's very interesting that both have very different recollections of the same event. He's been dining out on the story for multiple years and she point-blank denies it occurred.

Comment: @django is that update _the answer_? If so it 100% shouldn’t be in the question.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot No, it's a more detailed telling of the events in the question. I found this question after watching the video, because I also wanted to know if it was true or not

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt okay I didn’t click through, seemed like it might have been Stephen Fry essentially answering the question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## UPDATE: Rowling has apparently just addressed this on Twitter.

> Good story, but it isn't true! @stephenfry wasn't condescending, he was completely lovely, and that phrase isn't in 4 books! #factsmatter
>
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/869472397577117696)</sub>

Original answer below.

---

## Almost, but not quite

**Book 4: "Harry pocketed it"**

> He pulled Sirius’s reply off Pigwidgeon’s leg, **Harry pocketed it**, and they  hurried back to  Gryffindor  Tower to read it. (Chapter 23)

**Book 5: "pocketed it"**

> 'Right-o,' Fred said brightly, spraying the Doxy quickly in the face so that it fainted, but the moment Mrs. Weasley's back was turned he **pocketed it** with a wink. (Chapter 6)

**Book 6: "pocketed it"**

> Not long  after this, Hagrid became  tearful again and pressed the whole unicorn tail upon Slughorn,  who **pocketed it** with cries of, “To friendship!  To generosity!  To ten  Galleons a  hair!” (chapter 22)

**Book 7: No pocketing :-(**

Note: While the question was only asking about the accuracy of the finale part, it should be noted that the phrase *Harry pocket it* is not found anywhere in *The Prisoner of Azkaban*, nor for that matter is the word *pocketed*.

## Bonus: At the OP's request, I am adding a list of all of the places that the word *pocketed* can be found in Harry Potter Canon.

**Harry pocketed it - 4 times**

> "Better get the cloak," Ron muttered, as Lee Jordan finally left, stretching and yawning. Harry ran upstairs to their dark dormitory. He putted out the cloak and then his eyes fell on the flute Hagrid had given him for Christmas. ***He* pocketed it** to use on Fluffy -- he didn't feel much like singing.
>   (PS16)
>
> "Well, it's not much use to you," said Ron. He dropped his voice. "Fifty points if you can get it through Myrtle's nose."
>   **Harry**, however, **pocketed it**.
>   (CS13)
>
> Mr. Diggory handed Harry his wand and **Harry pocketed it**. (GF9)
>
> He pulled Sirius’s reply off Pigwidgeon’s leg, **Harry pocketed it**, and they  hurried back to  Gryffindor  Tower to read it. (GF23)

**Pocketed it - 2 times**

> 'Right-o,' Fred said brightly, spraying the Doxy quickly in the face so that it fainted, but the moment Mrs. Weasley's back was turned he **pocketed it** with a wink. (OP6)
>
> Not long  after this, Hagrid became  tearful again and pressed the whole unicorn tail upon Slughorn,  who **pocketed it** with cries of, “To friendship!  To generosity!  To ten  Galleons a  hair!” (HBP22)

**Pocketed - 4 times**

> "We're going to talk now," said Riddle, still smiling broadly, and he **pocketed** Harry's wand.
>   (CS17)
>
> Each  wore an expression of utmost contempt, yet the unexpected  entrance of so many  witnesses seemed to have brought them to their senses.  Snape **pocketed** his wand(, turned on his heel)<sup>1</sup> and swept back across the kitchen, passing the Weasleys  without comment. At the door he looked  back. (OP24)
>
> He looked at Ron. "You saved everything because you felt lucky. You did it all yourself."
>   He **pocketed** the potion again. (HBP14)
>
> Then he returned to the Gaunt hovel, performed the complex bit of magic that would implant a false memory in his uncle's mind, laid Morfin's wand beside its unconscious owner, **pocketed** the ancient ring he wore, and departed." (HBP17)

**By book:**
Philosopher's Stone - 1 occurrence, *He* [harry] *pocketed it*
Chamber of Secrets - 2 occurrences, including *Harry(, however,) pocketed it.*
Prisoner of Azkaban - No occurrences
Goblet of Fire - 2 occurrences, both of which are *Harry pocketed it.*
Order of the Phoenix - 2 occurrences, including *pocketed it.*
Half-Blood Prince - 3 occurrences, including *pocketed it*
Deathly Hallows - no occurrences
Supplementary works - no occurrences
Interviews - no occurrences
Pottermore - no occurrences

---

<sup>1</sup> ", turned on his heel" was removed in later editions.

Comment: This might help. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctg8c.png

Comment: @ibid, for what it's worth, I was most curious about the accuracy which would mean books 3-7 or 4-7 indeed.  But I think that information about use of the phrase (or even just the word "pocketing") across the series would make for a more interesting answer in general.

Comment: "Interviews - no occurrences; Pottermore - no occurrences" These seem less relevant, as presumably Stephen Fry didn't do audiobook versions of Pottermore or JKR interviews :-)

Comment: @randal'thor - My answer was originally very concise, but the OP asked me to expand it with random information.

Comment: @Miles - all good

Answer (score 6):

Stephen Fry describes exactly this scenario in this video, right down to the condescending "good for you" remark.

https://twitter.com/bbcarts/status/1133060526920142848

Stephen Fry does offer a potential explanation for why Rowling said no, from 2:30 in the video.

> […] she [J. K. Rowling] had wanted the audiobook to be complete, unabridged, not condensed in any way as sometimes audiobooks are. Because she felt that if children are reading it and listening at the same time, they would be annoyed if it was different. So it was very important that we got it exactly right.

So...at least according to Fry, this story is accurate (though it's worth noting that he states that the phrase "appears in every subsequent book", so either he is mistaken or exaggerating for effect).

Comment: Adding a transcript of the salient parts would be a good idea, especially if the link goes dead.

Comment: @Valorum I added part of the transcript that doesn't just tell the anecdote the same as in the question.

Comment: @b_jonas - Cheers. Much obliged.